# In case of multiple when and then blocks is it possible to continue running another block if one fails?

Tags: groovy, spock, geb

I have a test class:

```
class Homepage extends AbstractTest {
    @TestCase('TC44424')
    def "Rust Checkout - Homepage gallery blade"() {
        given:
        code....

        when:
        code..

        then:
        code..

        when:
        code..

        then:
        code..
    }
}
```

So here if suppose my first When-Then block fails I don't want my script to fail I want it to go to another When-Then block and continue running.Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you want to continue if a block fails?

Answer (score 0):

Since these test cases aren't building up any state (and thus you think they could continue running after a previous one fails), you might consider putting each `when`/`then` in their own test method. You can move the `given` to a `def setup() { ... }` method as well.

Alternatively, you could construct your test with a `where` block. This might not be feasible depending on how different each test case is from each other.